# Really struggling with sub procedures while making star drawing program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Im trying to create a sub procedure which draws a sequence of spaces and stars, and then outputs the result. The user enters in the amount of stars and the amount of spaces they would like and then outputs the stars and spaces drawn onscreen. For example, DrawStars(4,5) would output ----*****.

Here is my code so far:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim Spaces As Integer = 0
    Dim Stars As Integer = 0
    Dim TotalChars As Integer = 0

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of spaces you want to enter")
    Spaces = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of stars you want to enter")
    Stars = Console.ReadLine

    TotalChars = Spaces + Stars

    DrawStars(Spaces, Stars, TotalChars)

    Console.WriteLine("")

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub DrawStars(ByVal Spaces As Integer, ByVal Stars As Integer, ByVal TotalChars As Integer)
    Dim Output As String

    Do Until TotalChars = Stars + Spaces
        If Spaces > 0 The
            Output = Console.ReadLine
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("*")
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: you need 2 For Loops one for the number of spaces and one for stars, just have them add to the same output var; it doesnt need `totalchars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your condition. `TotalChars` is already `Stars + Spaces` according `Main`.

```
Do Until TotalChars = Stars + Spaces  '<-- Already True!
    If Spaces > 0 The
        Output = Console.ReadLine
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("*")
    End If
Loop
```

You also weren't incrementing `TotalChars` so let's just swap to 2 `For` loops since **@dotnetom** already showed an easy way to create a string with spaces and stars.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Spaces
    Console.Write(" ")
Next
For i As Integer = 1 To Stars
    Console.Write("*")
Next
```

*This shouldn't be intended as a copy and paste solution. It's more of an example and what issue I saw with your code =)*

Comment: Then is there a way to easily allow the user to go onto the next line and keep going, creating like a picture?

Comment: @JeffCottonBWFC  add another parameter to indicate the number of lines to repeat

Comment: @JeffCottonBWFC Based on the question and code you provided, I really do not know exactly what kind of output you were expecting. You had an `Output` variable that was completely unused and `Spaces ` was always going to be `> 0`.

Comment: I was trying to get the code to create a picture after the user enters the amount of lines and stars. I have to get the procedure to draw an image onscreen but i can't seem to do that with the code

Comment: if you mean you want a linefeed after either of these, just add `Console.WriteLine()` to either answer....the question asks about *spaces* and stars not *lines* and stars

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case would be to create 2 strings using [this constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Sub DrawStars(ByVal Spaces As Integer, ByVal Stars As Integer, ByVal TotalChars As Integer)
    Console.Write(new String(" "C, Spaces))
    Console.Write(new String("*"C, Stars))
End Sub
```

The above code is not protected from invalid input parameters.

Comment: I think he wants them on the same line

Comment: The problem is, the code needs to have spaces to help indent to create the picture which can span down multiple lines if needed